# How can i view a list in text field when i press the @ key

Tags: flutter, dart, messaging

I want to achieve this functionality, when i type the @ key on the keyboard, i want the textfield to show a list of dummy users returned from a List widget, i want to copy the whatsapp or facebook feature whereby you press @ and it gives list of available users in chat [here is an example of what i want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iup92.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is too broad. Are you stuck on listening the keyboard event for "@"? Or is this a ui related question? Then, at what point you are stuck? Please consider to edit your question in this manner.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i wan't to listen for the "@" key and when pressed i want a list of users to show in the textfeild

Comment: There is callback function named onChanged to listen TextField input. There you can check the first character of the input and show whatever you want. Try and add some code to your question if you get stuck somewhere.